# Cannot store data in dd/mm/yyyy format in SQL Sserver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

```
for (i = 0; i < u; i++)
{
    String date = dates.Cast<string>().ElementAt(i).ToString();

    date = date.Remove(0, 1);
    date = date.Remove(8,1);
    date = date.Insert(6, "20");
    date = date.Replace('-', '/');
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

    String Subject = sr.ReadLine();

    CommandText = "Insert into Subject_Title(Date, Subject) values(@Date, @Subject)";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = dt;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.Text);
    cmd.Parameters["@Subject"].Value = Subject;

    int ii = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Here I'm trying to make the dt object of type datetime in format dd/mm/yyyy which I'm not able to do and its storing in database in format `yyyy-mm-dd`..

Do help me out. .

Comment: What happens if you use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt); instead?

Comment: how it is stored, is irrelevant, if the date is stored correctly (*the correct date*). What you need is to format it when you display it (*not when you store it*).

Comment: Have you tried considering `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string format = "dd-mm-yyyy";
        string dtTObeInsertedInSQL = dt.ToString(format);`

Comment: Send a datetime variable from your application, not a string.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot store it? Do you get an error? If so: **what** error? Do you get no data stored at all? Wrong data? If so: **wrong how??**

Answer (score 0):

This is two different view, storing `DateTime` does not need any format, since it is actually a `float` number (you can cast `DateTime` to `float` in `sql`), but presenting is something different, when you retrived you data you can format it via `ToShortDateString()` , `ToLongDateString()` or `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`